# MySQL SUM() Operatiion

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a MySQL table `payment` where I store all the payment related data of my client. The table fields are: `fileNo`, `clientName`, `billNo`, `billAmount`, `status`. I want to build a search form where I will input the `fileNo` or the `clientName`, which will yield a table fetching all the records for that file number or the client name where `status = 0` (unpaid). Here `billAmount` is a floating point number.

I am no good in MySQL, but here is my version of the SQL by fileNo

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `payment` WHERE `fileNo` = '$fileNo' AND `status` = '0'";
```

SQL by clientName

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `payment` WHERE `clientName` = '$clientName' AND `status` = '0'";
```

either way I make the query, I will also need to show the total unpaid amount against that fileNo or clientName.

From my understanding, the SUM() operation should be something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(billAmount) AS `unpaid` WHERE `fileNo` = '$fileNo' AND `status` = '0'";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(billAmount) AS `unpaid` WHERE `clientName` = '$clientName' AND `status` = '0'";
```

My question is, am I correct with my SUM() operation? And how do I get the total unpaid amount that I selected as `unpaid`? can I store it in a variable?

Any idea, suggestions or resource link will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think u should use the second query but u missed WHEre clause

```
   $sql = "SELECT SUM(billAmount) AS `unpaid` FROM payment WHERE `clientName` = '$clientName' AND `status` = '0'";
```

your total amount unpaid yes u cant get it as variable like that

```
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   ehco   $row['unpaid'] ;          <------ this will give you the unpaid amount.
```

of course after u fetch your query .

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is quite right, don't forget the FROM clause :

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(billAmount) AS `unpaid` FROM payment WHERE `clientName` = '$clientName' AND `status` = '0'";
```

Be careful if your client's name possibly contains quotes (have a look on addslashes function)

Then, to get the sum :

```
$sum = current(mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql)));
```

Answer (score 0):

---

BTW

In this query you have missed out `FROM` Clause :-)

```
 "SELECT SUM(billAmount) AS `unpaid` 
FROM payment
WHERE `fileNo` = '$fileNo' 
AND  `clientName` = '$clientName'
 AND `status` = '0'";
```

Yes it is possible to store a value in a variable from first query and to be used in a secondaries.
I wish if I could give you a proper sample from SQLFIDDLE, on mobile now. Will update later if you can try this code.